# Do I need constructor in TestNG class to initialise helper class objects and instance variables?

Tags: testng

I am calling certain helper methods from `TestNG` test class to call API endpoints and retrieve responses. And validate response object. Below is one of the example of one of my `TestNG` test class

In the below class, I am initialising helper objects along with declaration. Is it a good practice? or should I initialise in contructor or @BeforeClass method?

```java
public class GetPaymentDetailsTests extends TestBase {
    String authToken = Partner.get(WithScope.CHECKOUT_USER_GROUP).getBasicToken();
    String partnerId = Partner.get((WithScope.CHECKOUT_USER_GROUP)).getPartnerId();
    String requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    MerchantAdapterHelper merchantAdapterHelper = new MerchantAdapterHelper();
    CustomerAdapterHelper customerAdapterHelper = new CustomerAdapterHelper();
    GopayAPIsHelper gopayAPIsHelper = new GopayAPIsHelper();
    public static final String redirectURL = "https://www.google.com";

    @Test(groups = {Categories.SMOKE_PAYMENT_EXPERIENCE, Categories.REGRESSION_PAYMENT_EXPERIENCE, Categories.CHECKOUT, Categories.GOPAY_APIS, Categories.PAYMENT_EXPERIENCE, Countries.ID})
    public void validateGetPaymentDetailsAPIByReferenceID(){
        Customer customer = customerHelper.getCustomer(CustomerGroup.P2M_ONLINE);

        CollectResponse collectPaymentResponse = merchantAdapterHelper.linkWalletAndInitiateCollectPaymentRequest(authToken, requestId, partnerId, OnlineMerchants.JD_ID.getMerchantID(), customer, 2, redirectURL, "en_EN" );
        String referenceID = merchantAdapterHelper.getParamValueFromnextActionURL(collectPaymentResponse.getData().getNext_action().getRedirect_to_url(), "reference");

        Assert.assertEquals(gopayAPIsHelper.getPaymentDetailsByReferenceID(referenceID).getHttpStatusCode(), HttpStatus.SC_OK, "Failed to get Get Payment Details response");
    }

    @Test(groups = {Categories.SMOKE_PAYMENT_EXPERIENCE, Categories.REGRESSION_PAYMENT_EXPERIENCE, Categories.CHECKOUT, Categories.GOPAY_APIS, Categories.PAYMENT_EXPERIENCE, Countries.ID})
    public void validateGetPaymentDetailsAPIResponseByStateID(){
        Customer customer = customerHelper.getCustomer(CustomerGroup.P2M_ONLINE);

        CollectResponse collectPaymentResponse = merchantAdapterHelper.linkWalletAndInitiateCollectPaymentRequest(authToken, requestId, partnerId, OnlineMerchants.TEST_USER_SOURABH.getMerchantID(), customer, 2, redirectURL, "en_EN" );
        String stateID = merchantAdapterHelper.getParamValueFromnextActionURL(collectPaymentResponse.getData().getNext_action().getRedirect_to_url(), "id");

        Assert.assertEquals(gopayAPIsHelper.getPaymentDetailsByStateID(stateID).getHttpStatusCode(), HttpStatus.SC_OK, "Failed to get Get Payment Details response");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the objects of helper class contain any state (class fields) which may be modified during any method invocation, which might impact the next test case, then the current approach has to be used.

If the helper methods are used just for invocation of the methods, then as you said you could create an object in a `@BeforeClass` method, so that you do not create an object for each and every test, which would be unnecessary.

If the helper class is defined by you and if it holds only the methods to invoke the API's, then I would suggest you to define all those methods as `static`. This would allow you to invoke the methods without object creation, which is ideally how a helper/utility class should be.

Comment: Thanks @gautham-m
Understood your point.
So in my scenario, use of constructor is not required, right?

Comment: No. `BeforeClass` would be good. But I would still recommend using `static` methods

Comment: Yes, I agree with you